# Is DockPanel not available in Windows IOT Core

Tags: c#, wpf, win-universal-app, iot

I'm trying to make my first Universal Windows app for Windows IOT Core.  I'm reusing some code that I had previously used on a regular Windows WPF app (I guess they call it "classic desktop").  Trying to use a dockpanel, I get the error:

> Unknown type 'DockPanel' in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'

Searching online for "unknown type "dockpanel: in xml namespace +iot" returns zero results.  In general I haven't had much success at finding sample UW/IOT core applications out there to learn from.

Is this not available in Universal Windows?  Or am I missing some prerequisite?

Here's the code:

```
    <Grid Margin="5" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=me}">
    <Rectangle x:Name="backgroundRect" Fill="LightGray" Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="2" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" />
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DockPanel is only avaiable in WPF. See this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c04de4e-ebeb-4900-a7c1-62d85818debc/dockpanel-replacement?forum=winappswithcsharp).

Depends on the layout you want to achieve, but you can use a Grid as a replacement:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

      <!-- Fill up remaining space -->
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> 
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Stuff" />
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" />
  </Grid>
```

Comment: I wonder if there's a comprehensive list of what's missing from WPF in universal windows?